# Rails 5 Form: Loop through a collection to get a list of questions, but update a different Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models:
CompanyQuestion and UserAnswer

CompanyQuestion has_many UserAnswers, and UserAnswers belongs_to CompanyQuestion

CompanyQuestion has a :question attribute, "The person I'd most like to meet..."

UserAnswer has :answer and :company_question_id attributes.

On the User's profile, I'd like to loop through all the CompanyQuestions with textareas for the User to enter their answer and then submit their answers.

===

What's your favorite book?
[ TEXTAREA ]

Who is the most famous person you've met?
[ TEXTAREA ]

===

I've accomplished the looping but I'm not sure how to configure the form helper to follow the Rails way of updating the UserAnswer models.

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <%= form_for question do |form| %>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= form.label question.question %>
        <%= form.text_area ... %>
      </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I think [this is what you need](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-fields_for). Then in your  `QuestionsController` action just create a new `UserAnswer` model for each object you will get through your `params`

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I was able to get this to work using:

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
  <% @answer = UserAnswer.find_by('user_id = ? AND company_question_id = ?', current_user.id, question.id) %>
  <%= form_with(model: @answer, local: true) do |form| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= form.label question.question %>
      <%= form.text_area :answer, class: 'form-control' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I won't mark this as answered for a while in case someone recommends a better convention I should follow.